# What is the meaning of "as much as competition" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, as

Here is the sentence:

> The more intensive, more far-flung commerce of the early modern age required a clearer distribution of functions and cooperation **as much as competition**. ([source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Pcf1nrvUwD0C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22functions%20and%20cooperation%20as%20much%20as%20competition.%22&source=bl&ots=IPeL4jxdqX&sig=YYno1hS7q85ohSGaqLcms1ozZw0&hl=hi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwietM2BgsjWAhXIpY8KHcEtC5IQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22functions%20and%20cooperation%20as%20much%20as%20competition.%22&f=false))

I can't understand the relationship between the words "clearer distribution of functions and cooperation" and "competition". Why are they connected by "as much as"?

Comment: It would seem more "logical" with a comma after ***functions*** (because [**cooperation** as much as **competition**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cooperation+as+much+as+competition%22) is such an obvious juxtaposition it's practically a cliche). But presumably your cited writer specifically wanted to contrast the (by implication, less well-recognised) requirement for ***a clearer distribution of functions and cooperation*** against the need for ***competition*** when international trade took off in the modern age.

Comment: ...thus *I need A as much as B* would normally be said in contexts where it's *obvious* that I need B, but I'm pointing out that my need for A is equally pressing. It's similar to *I need A **as well as** as B*, but that version puts more emphasis on the fact that I need ***both*** things, where the "much" version emphasises ***equality of "need"***.

Answer (score 1):

> The more intensive, more far-flung commerce of the early modern age required:
>       1) a clearer distribution of functions
>   and
>       2) cooperation as much as competition.

The "as ... as" correlative here coordinates two parallel elements: cooperation and competition.

The phrasing in the second part of the compound direct object is not in canonical order.  A more neutral phrasing would be "as much cooperation as competition".  Moving "cooperation" to the front of this phrase is emphatic, stressing the contrast between the two elements and suggesting that cooperation was barely required if at all in the less intensive, more local commerce of prior ages.

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsis—the omission of repeated components— is very common in comparative constructions (*as .. as*, *more .. than*, &c); a comparative usually requires that the actual 'value' in the second part be omitted, and often reduces the second part to nothing but the contrasting component.

> John has more money than Jack has <s>much money</s>. ... *The element struck through is the obligatorily omitted value; and since* has *is common to both clauses, the sentence may be optionally reduced to*
>   John has more money than Jack <s>has</s>.

In your example, the obligatorily deleted value is something like *X much*, and the repeated subject and verb are optionally omitted:

> The more intensive, more far-flung commerce of the early modern age required a clearer distribution of functions and cooperation as much as <s>it required</s> competition <s>*X* much</s>.